# MultiThreading vs SingleThreading

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join

I've tested some simple conditions:
Consider an int array with 10 000 000 in length. Filling:

1. *using single (main) thread.*
2. *using double-worker threads and joining them until they finish. First one fills from the beginning until the middle of array. Second one from the end until the middle.*
3. *using ExecutorService fixed pool (2), calling execute and waiting for termination.*
4. *using ForkJoinPool with default amount of workers (amount of available processors)*

---

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PerformanceTest {
    private static final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 10_000_000;
    private static int[] array;
    private static final int ITERATIONS = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            array = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH];
            long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            singleWorkerFill();
            System.out.println("Single worker: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - millis));

            array = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH];
            millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            doubleWorkerFill();
            System.out.println("Double worker: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - millis));

            array = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH];
            millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            forkJoinWorkersFill();
            System.out.println("Executor workers: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - millis));

            array = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH];
            millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            executorWorkersFill();
            System.out.println("ForkJoin workers: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - millis));

            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private static void singleWorkerFill() {
        for (int i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
            array[i] = i;
        }
    }

    private static void doubleWorkerFill() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread worker1 = new Thread(new HeadArrayFiller());
        Thread worker2 = new Thread(new TailArrayFiller());
        worker1.start();
        worker2.start();
        worker1.join();
        worker2.join();
    }

    private static void executorWorkersFill() throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executorService.execute(new HeadArrayFiller());
        executorService.execute(new TailArrayFiller());
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private static void forkJoinWorkersFill() throws InterruptedException {
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
        pool.invoke(new HeadArrayFiller());
        pool.invoke(new TailArrayFiller());
        pool.shutdown();
        pool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private static class HeadArrayFiller extends RecursiveAction implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0, middle = array.length / 2; i <= middle; i++) {
                array[i] = i;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void compute() {
            run();
        }
    }

    private static class TailArrayFiller extends RecursiveAction implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = array.length - 2, middle = array.length / 2; i > middle; i--) {
                array[i] = i;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void compute() {
            run();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that single-threaded model has no chances vs. another ones, but it's not. Here's test results scaled in milliseconds:

```
ITERATION #1
Single worker: 7
Double worker: 10
Executor workers: 11
ForkJoin workers: 6
ITERATION #2
Single worker: 6
Double worker: 4
Executor workers: 5
ForkJoin workers: 4
ITERATION #3
Single worker: 4
Double worker: 4
Executor workers: 5
ForkJoin workers: 4
ITERATION #4
Single worker: 5
Double worker: 5
Executor workers: 5
ForkJoin workers: 4
ITERATION #5
Single worker: 5
Double worker: 5
Executor workers: 4
ForkJoin workers: 5
ITERATION #6
Single worker: 4
Double worker: 4
Executor workers: 5
ForkJoin workers: 4
ITERATION #7
Single worker: 4
Double worker: 4
Executor workers: 4
ForkJoin workers: 5
ITERATION #8
Single worker: 4
Double worker: 4
Executor workers: 4
ForkJoin workers: 5
ITERATION #9
Single worker: 4
Double worker: 4
Executor workers: 4
ForkJoin workers: 5
ITERATION #10
Single worker: 5
Double worker: 4
Executor workers: 4
ForkJoin workers: 4
```

As you noticed single-threaded model faster than multi-threaded double-worker at startup. Fork-join model seems to be the best likewise ExecutorService.
I suggest there're some JIT compiler optimizations over iterations. They are all quite similar at the end of the test.

Anyway the main question is **why double-threaded model performance is same as single-threaded** (and even slower at the cold startup). And how can I reach performance near twice faster as expected?

Thanks

Comment: You probably need a much larger example to see a big difference between `parallel` and `serial` processing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing 10M integers, for a modern computer, is a very fast task, and the gain of doing things in parallel, on two separate cores, doesn't compensate (or just compensates) the overhead of starting threads, context-switching between them, coordonating them, etc.

Start doing more more work at each iteration (like sleeping for 5 ms., for example), and the advantage of multi-threading will start to appear.

Comment: Just a few other possibilities: 1. the operation has further optimization opportunities with vectorization (SIMD instructions);
2. the optimizations above may or may not be successfully applied to "double thread" code because those loops are not so simple;
3. depending on minute details of memory access patterns we may get reduced performance from cache line sharing between cores;
4. the above is heavily impacted by whether the two threads run on the same hyperthreaded core or not; and on and on...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik this comment should be an answer. You would get my upvote. You know way more about low-level JIT and hardware stuff than I know.

Comment: It was supposed to be one, but close votes won the race. Thanks for the virtual upvote, though